# PHP: how to add array index then cut into several array?

Tags: php, arrays, split, divide

*I have make many changes but still cannot figure out.
i have an array let say: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
i just want to ask how to add this array until index 2 and continued add for rest array then divide them by 2 array each.*

> input : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ];
>
> process : [1+2+3, 4+5+6, 7+8+9, 10]
>
> output i need : [6,15,24,10]
>
> then i want to cut this array into 2
>
> last output : [[6,5],[24,10]]

Thanks

Comment: Combination of [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) (with a size argument of 3), [array_map()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) or [array_walk()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) doing an [array_sum()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) to add the groups of values; then [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) again with a size argument of 2

Comment: Thank Mark Barker. Got solution already :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code will be:

```
$data   = range(1,10);
$result = array_chunk(array_map('array_sum', array_chunk($data, 3)), 2);
```

-please, read [array functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) manual

Comment: It works!!..Hi Alma Do Mundo, thank you for this solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
<?php
$array = range(1, 10);

$array = array_chunk($array, 3);

$array = array_map('array_sum', $array);

$array = array_chunk($array, 2);

print_r(
    $array
);

/*
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 15
        )
        [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 24
            [1] => 10
        )
    )
*/
```

Comment: Hi Anthony Sterling, thank you for this solution. Your solution work too.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a for cycle to sum what you need then store result in new array. Another solution is using [array merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). When you've done the trick you can create a  [multidimensional array](http://webcheatsheet.com/PHP/multidimensional_arrays.php) to get the result like [[6,5],[24,10]].

Hope it helps

Comment: Already got solution from Alma Do Mundo and Anthony Sterling. By the way, thanks Stefano Bosio :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't really see what you are getting at from the question, but I think PHP's array_chunk command may be your friend on this, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

this will allow you to split the array into chunks of 3 (or any number) of elements with last element containing the remainder (in this case 1 element)

Comment: i wanna use for the google chart. By the way, got answer already. Thanks Pete Ravenscroft :)